# Resultados duplicados

Tags: php, mysql, select, phpmyadmin, sql-select

Tenho duas tabelas

- produto:{
  pid
  pnome
  valor
  categoria
  estoqueP
  estoqueM
  estoqueG

  }
- fotos{
  fid
  fnome
  produto
  }

E estou tentando fazer uma consulta no banco onde preciso pegar tudo o que está na tabela produto todos os produtos, pra isso estou usando uma função no PHP, mas o problema é que cada produto tem várias fotos, então na hora de exibir os produtos ele exibe os mesmos produtos com cada foto, mas eu queria exibir o produto apenas uma vez com apenas uma das fotos, abaixo o código da função junto com a pesquisa no banco

```
public static function website_produtos_home(){
        $pdo = db::pdo();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT p.*, f.fnome FROM produto AS p JOIN fotos AS f ON p.pid = f.produto");
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($total > 0){
            while ($dados = $stmt-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo 
                "<div class='col-3'>
                    <ul class='grid'>
                        <li>
                            <a href='produto/{$dados['pid']}'>
                                <img src='{$dados['fnome']}' alt=''>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='grid-descricao'>
                            <ul>
                                <a href=''><li class='grid-nome'>{$dados['pnome']}</li></a>
                                <li class='grid-preço'>Preço: R$ {$dados['valor']}</li>
                                <li class='grid-quantidade'>Tamanho P: {$dados['estoqueP']} unidades</li>
                                <li class='grid-quantidade'>Tamanho M: {$dados['estoqueM']} unidades</li>
                                <li class='grid-quantidade'>Tamanho G: {$dados['estoqueG']} unidades</li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <a href='produto/{$dados['pid']}'><li class='grid-detalhes'>Detalhes</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Criei mais um campo na tabela "fotos" chamado "principal" com valor predefinido para 0, fui no registro das fotos que queria marcar e alterei para 1, depois mudei a pesquisa do banco para:

```
SELECT p.*, f.fnome FROM produto AS p JOIN fotos AS f ON p.pid = f.produto WHERE f.principal = 1
```

Agora está exibindo todos os produtos apenas uma vez

Comment: Uma outra maneira seria como aqui nesse post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12526264/4623423